# VB to C# Translate Event Handler that Implements Interface Event

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I was looking at code in WPF which is in VB. I am trying to convert it to C#. Eventhough I used VB .Net to C# converter I cannot figure out the correct syntax for the following code in C#. Any ideas how to write this in C#?

VB Code:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article should help:

[How to: Implement Interface Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx)

So in your case it should be (theoretically):

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```